# Dockerを使った機械学習のトレーニング精度を良くしたい

Tags: python, docker, 機械学習, 深層学習

Dockerを使って3種類の花の判別プログラム(.py)を作成しています。
プログラムを実行して8回のトレーニングを行いましたが、なぜかトレーニングうまくできませんでした。
これが学習の結果です。

[image]

lossもaccも一定の数値のままででした。

試しに、Dockerを使わずにそのままPythonプログラムを実行してみました。

[image]

トレーニングがうまく機能しました。

つまり、Dockerで機械学習を行うとなぜがトレーニングがうまくいかない現象が起きてしまいます。

私の予想では、DockerのメモリやCPUの設定が機械学習と合わなかったのではないかと考えました。Dockerで使用できるメモリやCPUを何らかの方法で増やせばいいのかと思っています。

どなたか解決方法やアドバイスをいただきたいです。

### 仕様スペック

・windows10
・Docker Toolbox
・Python3.7.3

### ソースコード

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gc
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils

from mutagen.mp3 import MP3 as mp3
import pygame
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras.backend import tensorflow_backend as backend

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import cv2
#
# モデルを生成
#
class TrainModel :
  def __init__(self):
    input_dir = './Gazo'
    self.nb_classes = len([name for name in os.listdir(input_dir) if name != ".DS_Store"])
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = np.load("./Gakushu.npy")
    # データを正規化する
    self.x_train = x_train.astype("float") / 256
    self.x_test = x_test.astype("float") / 256
    self.y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, self.nb_classes)
    self.y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, self.nb_classes)

  def train(self, input=None) :
    model = Sequential()
    # K=32, M=3, H=3
    if input == None :
      model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=self.x_train.shape[1:]))
    else :
      model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=input))

    # K=64, M=3, H=3（調整）
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    # K=64, M=3, H=3（調整）
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512))
    # biases  nb_classes
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(self.nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    if input == None :
      # 学習してモデルを保存
      #model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10)
      fit = model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=8, validation_data=(self.x_test,self.y_test))
      fig, (axL, axR) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10,4))

      axL.plot(fit.history['val_loss'],label="loss for validation")
      axL.set_title('model loss')
      axL.set_xlabel('epoch')
      axL.set_ylabel('loss')
      axL.legend(loc='upper right')

      #axR.plot(fit.history['acc'],label="loss for training")
      axR.plot(fit.history['val_acc'],label="acc for validation")
      axR.set_title('model accuracy')
      axR.set_xlabel('epoch')
      axR.set_ylabel('accuracy')
      axR.legend(loc='upper right')

      fig.savefig('./Wao.png') #グラフの画像が保存される
      plt.close()

      hdf5_file = "./AImodel.hdf5"
      model.save_weights(hdf5_file)

      # modelのテスト
      score = model.evaluate(self.x_test, self.y_test, verbose = 0)
      print('loss=', score[0])
      print('accuracy=', score[1])
      img = cv2.imread('./Wao.png')
      cv2.imshow('精度と損失', img)
      cv2.waitKey(0)
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
  args = sys.argv
  train = TrainModel()
  train.train()
  gc.collect()
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.3
WORKDIR /app
COPY T_test.py /app/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim && apt-get install -y curl
RUN pip install icrawler==0.6.2 Keras==2.2.4 numpy==1.16.2 opencv-python==4.1.1.26 pandas==0.25.1 Pillow==6.1.0 pygame==1.9.6 scikit-learn==0.21.3 tensorflow==1.13.1 mutagen==1.42.0 matplotlib==3.1.1
EXPOSE 4226
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker Desktop を使用している場合、タスクトレイのアイコンを右クリックして「Settings」を開き、「Advanced」でCPUやメモリの割当量を調整することができます。

Comment: 割り当てられる限界まで設定してトレーニングを行いましたが変化なしでした。（割り当てたメモリは約5GB、CPU数は4つ）

Comment: docker stats　を使ってコンテナの稼働中コンテナのリソース使用状況を確認しながら、トレーニングを行ってみました。結果、メモリは十分以上に足りましたがCPUの稼働率が300%以上になり、600％行くこともありました。

Comment: 単純にPCのスペックが弱かったようです